# Checking R Package using just Makevars in src gives a warning

Tags: r

I have an [R Package](https://github.com/nachti/STATtools) including a dataset (csv) in `data-raw`. To create a binary file in `data` I use `Makevars` in the directory `src`. An Rscript located in `data-raw` is called and that's it. This causes a warning:

```
* checking package subdirectories ... WARNING
  Subdirectory ‘src’ contains no source files.
```

As at [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/nachti/STATtools) warnings are handled as errors I created a `dummy.cpp` file and put it to `src`.
Is there a better / recommended way to avoid this warning?

~g

Comment: Would it work to put `Makevars` in `inst`? It would be moved to the project root on install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Hadley Wickhams "R packages"? 
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

I would set your data into `inst -> extdata` in your package folder.

Comment: Of course I read it - as well as *writing r extensions*. Due to the fact that I don't want to add `data.table` as dependency, I added the *raw* data and an R script to create the *binary* data to the git repository. I also tried `inst/extdata` before, but the result was not satisfactory.